# how to restrict azure blob logging by size of log file or by day format

Tags: azure, logging, log4net, azure-blob-storage, azure-diagnostics

I have Azure Web App which is enabled with App Service Logs. All logs are stored in blob storage as shown in below.

[image]

Since it is logging for multiple times in an hours (/YYYY/MM/DD/hh/counter.log), if we have any prod issue it is so tough to download all the log files and investigate it.

Is it possible to keep the log format as based on log file size (or) or by day?.

Example : **when log file  reaches 2MB then it will create new log file. (or)  log multiple file per day basis.**

This is possible in log4net.

Comment: Would you like to use app insights instead https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-insights-overview ?

Comment: Thanks Thomas, This options needs code changes. Unfortunately our code is Prod.we can not do the major code changes now. Do you recommend any other options which helps  to convert those blob logs into text file.

Comment: For the temporary solution I have created a powershell script that is running in my local. This grabs all log files from blob storage and create a log text file in local.